# Calculate min. win ratio needed for a bet to be profitable

Tags: finance-mathematics

If a bet 12000 to win 4000 my risk/reward ratio is .33 . 
How often must I win the bet to be profitable?
I know it's 75% but have not found the formula yet.

Comment: great thanks. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With probablility $p$ you win 4000, with probability $(1-p)$ you lose 12000 (or in other words you "win" -12000)

Write the expectation: $E=4000 p + (-12000)(1-p)$

Find the breakeven $p$ as the $p$ that sets the expectation to zero and solve for $p$:

$4000 p + (-12000)(1-p) = 0 \implies p=\frac{16000}{12000}=0.75$